# Get id from value in dropdown, send it to controller, load data and reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to display a dropdown, send id from value parameter to the controller, then load data and reload the page.

Imagine this. You are an admin of page. You have list of all users. Now you want to see projects and posts and comments of specific user. You have a dropdown, choose user and data will load his projects, posts and comments. Now you want to see data from another user. As before, you will choose another user in dropdown and data will reload and you will see them on the same page.

So far I know how to make a dropdown and get id to the jQuery code:

```
<%= select_tag "construction_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@constructions, "id", "title"), :onchange => "constructions_dropdown(this.value)", class: "form-control", id: "dropdown_const" %>
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="dropdown_const" name="construction_id" onchange="constructions_dropdown(this.value)">
    <option value="25">My construction</option>
    <option value="26">Another construction</option>
</select>
```

If I choose Another construction, I get the id by this:

```
function constructions_dropdown(construction_id) {
    alert(construction_id)
}
```

But what now? I am still on the index page. So maybe I should make a form_tag? And how should I send construction_id to the controller and assure that id is not nil and then load data? Because I think reload of the page should be done by submit of form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you should use Jquery Ajax to GET the information you want. From the results you can reload or print the new information http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: That is just a part of the answer. I know that I can and how send data to controller. But then I need to load data in controller (one question) and reload page. I think I need to use on change, submit, etc. But my knowledge of jQuery is not that good.

Comment: You can modify the inner html elements to delete the old options and assign the new ones. Another option is using the **select** element from jQuery UI: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#default